# Open Workspace during integration testing for vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, continuous-integration, integration-testing, devops, vscode-extensions

I have a use case where I need to have a workspace open in the host environment for vscode testing. I want to know a function to open a default workspace and another function which I can use with await so that the testing function waits till a workspace is opened.