# openTextDocument after opening a folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write unit tests that open a specific folder as a workspace, and then open a specific file and show it in the editor.

I tried using the `vscode.openFolder` command to open the folder which worked, but I cant seem to be able to open files after that's executed.

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder", wsUri);

const document = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(fileUri);
const editor = await vscode.window.showTextDocument(document);
```

also tried to open the file in `then`

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder", wsUri).then(async () => {
  const document = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(fileUri);
  const editor = await vscode.window.showTextDocument(document);
});
```

The behavior is that the folder opens but after that the document does not. 
If I try to open the document without opening the folder, it opens. But I need to open the folder first.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926105/open-workspace-during-integration-testing-for-vscode-extension